# How do I export activities related to an account with a specific recordtype?

Tags: data-loader, polymorphic

I am looking to export events and tasks from one organisation to another for all account records with a specific recordtype.

Is there a way I can query tasks and events which are related to accounts with a specific recordtype? This would include opportunities as well whose account recordtype will also be of specific recordtype.

Comment: Isn't any demonstrated effort required? This is just a work order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're in luck: you don't have to wait until Summer '19 hits your org, bringing with it [Polymorphic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm#!), or use a subquery on `WhatId`, because you can query through the non-polymorphic [`AccountId` relationship](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336268&language=en_US&type=1) on the Task and Event objects:

```
SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'My_Record_Type'
```

Opportunities don't have any polymorphic relationships, so they're no more than an ordinary relationship query:

```
SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'My_Record_Type'
```

Comment: Really.. That's so exciting to hear.